# c# textbox to database

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dataGridView, textBoxFirstName, buttonSelect and buttonUpdate on a C# WinForm. I have the codes at the end of my question.

When I click the buttonSelect button, the select result comes to the dataGridView and textBoxFirstName without a problem. When I select different records from dataGridView, the textBoxFirstName is getting updated automatically too.

When I change "FirstName" field from the dataGridView and click buttonUpdate, the FirstName field is being saved to the database without a problem.

But when I change "FirstName" from the textBoxFirstName, the data is not being saved to the database when I click buttonUpdate.

How can can I make the FirstName field to be saved to the database when the change is made from the textBoxFirstName and buttonUpdate is clicked?

Thank you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private const string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=AdventureWorks2008R2;Trusted_Connection=True";
    private SqlConnection con;
    private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    private void FillGrid(string sqlCommand)
    {
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand, con);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
        textBoxFirstName.DataBindings.Clear();
        textBoxFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataTable, "FirstName");
    }

    private void buttonSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillGrid("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Person.Person");
    }

    private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Ravi but he doesn't use any parameters in his query

Comment: @AndreyGordeev he use inline SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Person.Person.  and using* in sql is more costly

Comment: thank you. this code is an example for explaining the problem shortly. security and performance is not so important for this example.

Comment: @jack85, check if the changes you madke in textbox are affecting on `dataTable`

Comment: @Andrey Gordeev I have just realized that, when I change textBoxFirstName and click another on the dataGridView, and then click to the buttonUpdate, the FirstName is getting saved to the database without a problem. but how can I make this saved without selecting another record on the dataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

That's because inside `buttonUpdate_Click` you're updating `dataAdapter` with the grid's data source. So whatever is in the grid gets stored in database, however, text in the textbox doesn't. You need to update the data adapter with `textBoxFirstName`'s data source too. Hope it helps.

Comment: Grid's datasource is `dataTable`. `textBoxFirstName` is bound to `dataTable` too

Comment: I tried all of the suggestions but unfortunately I still could not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

AS someone told you are not updating textbox's data when u click buttonupdate you are only updating gridviews data..Now try this.

```
private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource);
    textBoxFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataTable, "FirstName");
}
```

Comment: dataGridView and textBoxFirstName are using the same DataSource (dataTable):

    `dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
    textBoxFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataTable, "FirstName");`


Shouldn't the code below save both dataGridView and textBoxFirstName to the database since they are using the same DataSource?

    `dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource);`

Comment: @jack85 ya but in question itself both gridview and textbox have been bounded separately...

Comment: unfortunately the example above and the example below didn't solve the problem. I could not understand exactly where I am making the mistake  :\  
  
        `private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)textBoxFirstName.DataBindings[0].DataSource);  
            dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource);  
        }`